Windows COM in Julia
I want to use some Windows apps in Julia and this required installing Windows COM, which seems that it is not available in the standard Julia Package Registry. There was a suggestion to install PyCall in Julia and then use pywin32 library. How reliable is this solution? Any other suggestions?

Since your questions remains unanswered here, might I suggest to try it in https://discourse.julialang.org ? There is an active community which includes developers. Maybe they can help
